# How to save a Large Blob(>2.5GB) to file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I am fetching a file using HTTP get request. I am able to download large files(3GB or more) when I use `'responseType': 'blob'` But I am unable to save this Blob to a file.

Download Code:

```
this.http.get(downloadUrl, {headers: headers,
              'responseType': 'blob','reportProgress':true,observe: "events"}).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              switch (event.type) 
              {
                case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader: <some code here>
                case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress: <some code here>
                case HttpEventType.Response:
                {
                  const downloadedBlob = new Blob([event.body]);
                  saveAs(downloadedBlob, downloadDestPath);
```

Attempted approaches:

1. FileSaver.saveAs:

   1. Without path: When I use saveAs without any path/filename user is prompted to enter Filepath/Filename in a save file popup. Upon entering that, the file is getting saved correctly. But I want this to happen in the background without any user interaction.
   2. With Path: When I use saveAs with path, a tmp file is created of size 200-300MB and then is vanishes, without creating any new file.
2. Anchor Tag: I tried to use the Anchor tag manually as well, but results have been exactly similar to above mentioned FileSaver method. (Which is expected as saveAs uses anchor tag too)
3. fs.writefile: I have tried to write the file using fs.writefile, but that does not create any new file either.
4. Coverting: I tried to convert received Blob into an ArrayBuffer(which gives an error) and Stream (which returns empty).

Note:
`console.log(downloadedBlob)` shows the following:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console with the FileSaver.saveAs with path approach?

Comment: @JakeSmith No, there are no errors in console when I try to save the file with FileSaver.